# String (split and loop ) to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

can someone tell me where the below code is missing to get the correct data..

```
  var temprule="MO,WE"; 
    var rulest =[]; 
    var jsondata=[];
    rulest=temprule.split(',');
    console.log("TTTTT rulest", rulest);
    for(var j = 0; j < rulest.length; j++)
     { 
      var day=rulest[j];
      entry.day=day;
      console.log(entry.day) // log shows MO and WE as per loop 
      jsondata.push(entry); // but jsondata has 2 entries with day WE

      } 

      incorrect o/p ->[{day=WE},day=WE}] expected--> [{day=MO},day=WE}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable entry needs to be initialized inside the loop.

```
 var temprule="MO,WE"; 
var rulest =[]; 
var jsondata=[];

rulest=temprule.split(',');
console.log("TTTTT rulest", rulest);
for(var j = 0; j < rulest.length; j++)
 { 
  var entry={};
  var day=rulest[j];
  entry.day=day;
  console.log(entry.day) // log shows MO and WE as per loop 
  jsondata.push(entry); // but jsondata has 2 entries with day WE

  } 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
```

Here is the jsfiddle link with corrected code.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/07de3uvp/1/)